# How do i clear cookies in Soap UI?

Tags: cookies, soapui

When i call a webservice which sends response with "Set-Cookie" header, soapui caches the cookies for subsequent calls. How do i clear these cookies on subsequent calls?

Or is there a way to "not-accept" cookies from the endpoints in the response?

I am using free Soap UI 4.5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this post on eviware's [forum](https://www.eviware.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=13170) one of the responses show how to clear cookies

Comment: Thank you, I knew about scripting in SOAP UI, but did not know how to use it. I am accepting your answer since it showed me the path :)

Answer (score 1):

I read the [link](https://www.eviware.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=13170) from Abhishek in another answer to begin with, and found my answer on this [link](http://siking.wordpress.com/2013/07/25/soapui-cookie-management/):

For anyone who is looking for answer, here is what i am using now:

Basically, you have to create a testcase with the requests that you want to run, and you will get a Script editor in TestSteps, where you can use the following groovy script.

```
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport

def myCookieStore = HttpClientSupport.getHttpClient().getCookieStore()

def myCookies = myCookieStore.getCookies()

// find the session cookie
def sessionCookie
myCookies.each {
    // print all of them 
    log.info(it.name + " = " + it.value)
    if (it.name == "JSESSIONID"){
        sessionCookie = it
    }

}


// if you want to update the cookie value
// sessionCookie.value = "new cookie value here..."


// deleting all cookies
myCookieStore.clear()

// to delete only specific
//if (sessionCookie != null) {
//  sessionCookie.expiryDate = new Date()-1 // yesterday
//  myCookieStore.clearExpired(new Date()-1)
//}

// check if the cookies are really removed
myCookies = myCookieStore.getCookies()
log.info("After Removing Session Cookie");
myCookies.each {
    // print all of them 
    log.info(it.name + " = " + it.value)
}

// if you want to create your own cookie
//import org.apache.http.impl.Cookie.BasicClientCookie
//def myNewCookie = new BasicClientCookie("cookie_name", "cookie_value")
//myNewCookie.version = 1
//myNewCookie.domain = "qa.test"
//myCookieStore.addCookie(myNewCookie)

// or from another cookie
//def myNewCookie = new BasicClientCookie("cookie_name", interestingCookie.value)
```